# How to create a custom layer for Sampling in Keras Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, sampling

I'm building a CNN in Keras with a Tensorflow backend, and I'd like to introduce a custom layer that should perform the following:

- Output a tensor of same shape and dtype as the input tensor.
- The output is made of few samples of the input tensor, let's say 25%. The rest of the output tensor should be zeros.
- The samples must be picked at random, **such that the highest values pixel are sampled with higher probability**. In other words, the probability distribution should be the input tensor itself (normalized).

For now, I've managed to build a mockup where I pick the top 25% pixels of the input tensor and create an output tensor of same size only from them. But it is not a random sampling.

Ideally I'd like to use a tensorflow equivalent of : `np.random.choice(input_tensor, num_samples, input_tensor_normalized)` where the third argument is the probability distribution to follow. Note that this only works on 1D np.array.

I've heard of `tf.random.multinomial` but it's depreciated and `tf.random.categorical` takes `logits` as inputs (I don't think it's my case) and doesn't propose a probability distribution.

A possibility is to reshape the input tensor as a vector, perform 1D sampling in Tensorflow if there is a way, construct a similar vector with the sampled values at the corresponding index and zeros elsewhere, and then reshape as a tensor afterwards.

Any other idea?

Should I move to PyTorch?

Thank you very Much

Comment: here a complete example with Keras: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67123900/10375049

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `tf.random.categorical`. The logits are just the unnormalised log probabilities. So if you already have your probability distribution ready to go you can perform:

```
samples = tf.random.categorical(tf.log(input_tensor_normalized), num_samples)
```